# R tools to visualize summary statistics of financial time series

Tags: r

Is there a package or guidelines to produce the **typical finance tables** with the summary statistics of financial time series. Each time series would have a small graph, the current value, the latest change, and the range. See the example below:

#### Figure 1: Typical finance table I want:

[image]

For instance,  how can I create a table like in the picture from the data table `dat` in the working example below:

```
library(data.table)

# Generate time series with 3 variable V1, V2, V3
dat <- melt(data.table(Dates = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-01")+99, 1), V1 = c(1:100), V2 = c(101:200), V3 = c(201:300)), id.vars = 'Dates')

# I want a better visualization table than the simple summary stat table shown below:
ugly_table <- dat[order(Dates), .(Current = value[.N], 
                             Change = value[.N] - value[.N-1],
                             Min    = min(value),
                             Range  = max(value) - min(value),
                             Max    = max(value)), by = 'variable']
ugly_table
>    variable Current Change Min Range Max
1:       V1     100      1   1    99 100
2:       V2     200      1 101    99 200
3:       V3     300      1 201    99 300
```

Comment: There are plenty of useful tutorials online. For instance I just searched "sparklines in table in R" and found these two: [Combining data tables and sparklines](https://leonawicz.github.io/HtmlWidgetExamples/ex_dt_sparkline.html) and [Make Beautiful Tables with the Formattable Package](https://www.displayr.com/formattable/?utm_medium=Feed&utm_source=Syndication)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the keyword I was missing in my search: "sparklines". It is exactly what I'm trying to do, I will study this package.